# Cannot run Glimpse with ASP.NET MVC 5 Application on IIS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, glimpse

I have an ASP.NET MVC 5 application that is running on IIS and I want to use the **Glimpse Package** so that I can monitor all of the SQL calls that are being made within my application.

I have installed Glimpse using the **Nuget Package Manager Console** by using the command:

```
Install-Package Glimpse.MVC5
```

Since my application is running on IIS, I added the following commands to my **web.config** file:

```
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="glimpse" type="Glimpse.Core.Configuration.Section, Glimpse.Core" />
    </configSections>
</configuration>

<system.web>
    <httpModules>
        <add name="Glimpse" type="Glimpse.AspNet.HttpModule, Glimpse.AspNet"/>
    </httpModules>
    <httpHandlers>
        <add path="glimpse.axd" verb="GET" type="Glimpse.AspNet.HttpHandler, Glimpse.AspNet"/>
    </httpHandlers>
</system.web>

<system.webServer>
    <modules>
        <add name="Glimpse" type="Glimpse.AspNet.HttpModule, Glimpse.AspNet" preCondition="integratedMode"/>
    </modules>
    <handlers>
        <add name="Glimpse" path="glimpse.axd" verb="GET" type="Glimpse.AspNet.HttpHandler, Glimpse.AspNet"  preCondition="integratedMode" />
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

After these commands are in place and I try running my application through IIS, I get the following error:

`Could not load file or assembly 'Glimpse.AspNet' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.`

I know that Glimpse is really set up to work by building your application locally but I think you can get it to work on a remote server as well.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually got Glimpse up and running by making sure I installed all of the necessary NuGet packages for it.